# how to run raco command from a script?

Tags: racket, raco

What's the preferred way to run a `raco` command from a script?

I've been doing things like:

```
#lang racket
(system "raco frog -b")
```

but there has got to be a better solution.

Comment: Do you need to run a `raco` command as a part of a Racket script? Or do you just need a way to run a `raco` command?

Comment: Yes, I need to run a `raco` command as part of a Racket script.

Comment: Okay, this is going to sound brusque because people are going to think I don't know you, but... can't you pull up the raco source files and see if there's a programmatic interface?

Comment: ... so I took a quick one-minute look at the source, and ... I don't see a programmatic interface. I think in this case the response might well be that going straight to the source is the right idea here, and that frog itself should have a programmatic interface. Does it?

Comment: `frog` is just an example, I want a programmatic interface to anything that's using `raco` as its interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes indeed, there is a better way:

```
#lang racket
(require raco/all-tools)
(define v (all-tools))
(parameterize ([current-command-line-arguments (vector "-b")])
  (dynamic-require (second (hash-ref v "frog")) #f))
```

Many thanks to Sam Tobin-Hochstadt.

https://github.com/racket/racket-lang-org/pull/26#issuecomment-267160884

Comment: Note: you may want to parameterize `current-directory` as well.

Comment: Documentation for `raco/all-tools`: http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/command.html#%28mod-path._raco%2Fall-tools%29